# Select only group of records for where condition

Tags: t-sql

I have a table similar to this

```
   THid Sid TID Sealantid
    1   1   1   1
    2   1   2   1
    3   1   3   4
    4   1   4   1
    5   1   5   1
    6   1   6   1
    33  2   1   1
    34  2   2   1
    35  2   3   1
    36  2   4   1
    37  2   5   1
    38  2   6   1
    65  3   1   1
    66  3   2   1
    67  3   3   4
    68  3   4   1
    69  3   5   1
    70  3   6   1
    97  4   1   1
    98  4   2   1
    99  4   3   8
    100 4   4   1
    101 4   5   1
    102 4   6   1
    129 5   1   1
    130 5   2   1
    131 5   3   8
    132 5   4   1
    133 5   5   1
    134 5   6   1
    161 6   1   1
    162 6   2   1
    163 6   3   4
    164 6   4   1
    165 6   5   1
    166 6   6   1
    193 7   1   1
    194 7   2   1
    195 7   3   4
    196 7   4   1
    197 7   5   1
    198 7   6   1
    225 8   1   1
    226 8   2   1
    227 8   3   4
    228 8   4   1
    229 8   5   1
    230 8   6   1
    257 9   1   1
    258 9   2   1
    259 9   3   1
    260 9   4   1
    261 9   5   1
    262 9   6   1
    289 10  1   1
    290 10  2   1
    291 10  3   4
    292 10  4   1
    293 10  5   1
    294 10  6   1
```

Here I wanted to find records only Sid's "where all sealantid=1"

Simple query I tried this

```
select * from table where sealantid=1
```

but this gives me all sid's but I want only SID's, Tid's (1 to 6) where all the sealantid=1

In this table 2 , 9

Comment: Tried this no luck                                                                               select distinct THid,Sid,Tid,Sealant_id from tbl
where Sealantid =1 
and Tid not in (select distinct Tid from tbl
where Sealantid in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS with a subquery

Try this:

```
WITH SampleData AS (
     SELECT V.*
     FROM (VALUES 
     (1,   1,   1,   1)
    ,(2,   1,   2,   1)
    ,(3,   1,   3,   4)
    ,(4,   1,   4,   1)
    ,(5,   1,   5,   1)
    ,(6,   1,   6,   1)
    ,(33,  2,   1,   1)
    ,(34,  2,   2,   1)
    ,(35,  2,   3,   1)
    ,(36,  2,   4,   1)
    ,(37,  2,   5,   1)
    ,(38,  2,   6,   1)
    ,(65,  3,   1,   1)
    ,(66,  3,   2,   1)
    ,(67,  3,   3,   4)
    ,(68,  3,   4,   1)
    ,(69,  3,   5,   1)
    ,(70,  3,   6,   1)
    ,(97,  4,   1,   1)
    ,(98,  4,   2,   1)
    ,(99,  4,   3,   8)
    ,(100, 4,   4,   1)
    ,(101, 4,   5,   1)
    ,(102, 4,   6,   1)
    ,(129, 5,   1,   1)
    ,(130, 5,   2,   1)
    ,(131, 5,   3,   8)
    ,(132, 5,   4,   1)
    ,(133, 5,   5,   1)
    ,(134, 5,   6,   1)
    ,(161, 6,   1,   1)
    ,(162, 6,   2,   1)
    ,(163, 6,   3,   4)
    ,(164, 6,   4,   1)
    ,(165, 6,   5,   1)
    ,(166, 6,   6,   1)
    ,(193, 7,   1,   1)
    ,(194, 7,   2,   1)
    ,(195, 7,   3,   4)
    ,(196, 7,   4,   1)
    ,(197, 7,   5,   1)
    ,(198, 7,   6,   1)
    ,(225, 8,   1,   1)
    ,(226, 8,   2,   1)
    ,(227, 8,   3,   4)
    ,(228, 8,   4,   1)
    ,(229, 8,   5,   1)
    ,(230, 8,   6,   1)
    ,(257, 9,   1,   1)
    ,(258, 9,   2,   1)
    ,(259, 9,   3,   1)
    ,(260, 9,   4,   1)
    ,(261, 9,   5,   1)
    ,(262, 9,   6,   1)
    ,(289, 10,  1,   1)
    ,(290, 10,  2,   1)
    ,(291, 10,  3,   4)
    ,(292, 10,  4,   1)
    ,(293, 10,  5,   1)
    ,(294, 10,  6,   1)
    ) AS V (THid, Sid, TID, Sealantid)
)
SELECT DISTINCT SD.Sid
FROM SampleData AS SD
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM SampleData AS C
  WHERE SD.Sid = C.Sid AND C.Sealantid <> 1
)
```

[You can try it on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/17164)

An alternative could be LEFT JOIN or NOT IN

```
SELECT DISTINCT SD.Sid
FROM SampleData AS SD 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT Sid FROM SampleData WHERE Sealantid <> 1
) AS C
ON SD.Sid = C.Sid
WHERE c.Sid IS NULL

SELECT DISTINCT SD.Sid
FROM SampleData AS SD 
WHERE SD.Sid NOT IN ( 
SELECT DISTINCT Sid FROM SampleData WHERE Sealantid <> 1
)
```

Comment: It's working on the above particular records but I have tables with millions of records. It's not working on my original table

Comment: I have added two alternatives, one use LEFT JOIN and the other use NOT IN.

Comment: If it takes long time too evaluate to add a non clustered index on columns Sid and Sealantid. Show plan on SSMS and see what indexes it suggest to add

Answer (score 1):

You can use gruop by with having:

```
 Select sid
 From table
 Group by sid
 Having min(sealantId) = 1
 And max(sealantId) = 1
```

Comment: @Ezin82 Glad to read that! Of course, the solution I'm proposing is only helpful when you want only the sid, if you want all columns you still need to select from the table twice, so I'm not sure it will have any performance benefit over the solution in your answer.